# Built-in build variable which references the workspace's root directory in Eclipse Java IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

In the Eclipse Java IDE does there exist a (built-in) build variable which references the workspace's root directory?

Answer (score 2):

`workspace_loc`:

> Returns the absolute file system path of the workspace root. When an argument is specified, the absolute file system path of the resource identified by a workspace relative path is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, there exists such variable.

But, you can create your own workspace directory, and specify that location in the command line of your eclipse.exe, using

```
"-data <path to  your workspace>".
```